# Python cx-freeze issue

Tags: python, linux, cx-freeze

Wanted to create a stand alone binary executable from a python module with cx freeze.

```
[root@frost-pc ~]# find / -name freeze.py

/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py

[root@frost-pc ~]# python2 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py /home/frost/Desktop/dd.py
```

And nothing happens, freeze.py just runs for a 3 seconds and it does not output binary file.

Comment: You are not running cx_freeze, you are running pip freeze, which is a different thing. [docs for pip freeze: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-freeze] ["Output installed packages in requirements format."]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using wrong command: `freeze.py` in `pip/commands` directory is for [`pip freeze`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-freeze) command.

Use `cxfreeze` program.

```
cxfreeze /home/frost/Desktop/dd.py
```

See [`cxfreeze script`](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/script.html#script) for usage detail.